LDAPJS-Client [[UnwillingToPerformError]: null] error
I want to update the sAMAccountName users domain password but I am getting UnwillingToPerformError while doing the same.
Here is the code:
try {
  await client.bind(ADUsername, ADPassword);

  const options = {
    filter: `(sAMAccountName=${username})`,
    scope: "sub",
    // attributes: ["displayName", "cn", "sn"],
    attributes: ["sAMAccountName"],
  };
  const searchResults = await client.search("dc=(organizationName),dc=in", options);
  console.log(searchResults);
  
  if (!searchResults || searchResults.length === 0) {
    // await client.unbind();
    return res.status(404).json({ Message: "User not found in LDAP." });
  }

  const userDN = searchResults[0].dn;
  console.log(userDN);
  const encodedPassword = Buffer.from(`"${password}"`, "utf-16le");
  // Modify user password in AD
  const ADResponse = await client.modify(userDN, [
    {
      operation: "replace",
      modification: {
        unicodePwd: encodedPassword,
      },
    },
  ]);
  console.log(ADResponse);
  // await client.unbind();
  return res
    .status(200)
    .json({ Message: "Password updated successfully." });
} catch (error) {
  console.error("LDAP error:", error);
  await client.unbind();
  return res
    .status(500)
    .json({ Message: "Failed to update password in LDAP" });
} finally {
  await client.unbind();
}

when i try userPassword instead of unicodePwd i am getting response as Password updated but as per documentation i need to use unicodePwd which throws an LDAP Error.
